# Как вызвать функцию для каждой количественной переменной датафрейма?

Tags: r

Например, для одного столбца будет так:

```
r = shapiro.test(iris[,1])
```

А как это сделать для всех неколичественных столбцов?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18503177/4827341

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтобы применить функцию к выбранным столбцам набора данных (matrix, dataframe, и т.д. и т.п.), можно воспользоваться [функцией `apply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/apply):

```
> apply(набор.данных[, столбцы], FUN=функция, MARGIN=2)
```

параметр `MARGIN` определяет, что будет выбираться из набора данных — строки (`1`) или столбцы (`2`). (вообще можно передать и вектор из нескольких значений — см. документацию).

---

под «количественными» данными, вероятно, подразумевалось то, для чего [функция `is.numeric()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/is.numeric) вернёт «истину».

если так, то можно получить вектор значений «истина/ложь» для набора данных, например, с помощью [функции `sapply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/sapply):

```
> sapply(набор.данных, is.numeric)
```

ну а с помощью функции `which()` из этого вектора можно получить уже список столбцов:

```
> which(sapply(набор.данных, is.numeric))
```

который уже можно подставить и в первую из приведённых команд:

```
> apply(набор.данных[, which(sapply(набор.данных, is.numeric))], FUN=функция, MARGIN=2)
```

---

в вопросе присутствует разночтение: столбцы должны быть то ли количественными, то ли наоборот неколичественными. разница будет лишь в том, что значение, возвращаемое функцией `is.numeric()`, надо инвертировать. например, с помощью `!`:

```
> ! sapply(набор.данных, is.numeric)
```